# Disable Keyboard for Particular Window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How I can disable keyboard in some particular window?

I want if a window is open then keyboard should not do anything.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there a text field in the window, or does the keyboard show up automatically when you open the window?

Comment: @OGH: not ios, osx :)

Comment: Look at this website. I'm not too familiar with osx. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH7-SW1

Answer (score 0):

you can return NO from the NSWindow's canBecomeKeyWindow method. That disables the keyboard for the window

Comment: Or if i added multiple views on window, can i disable keyboard for particular view for that window?